# Compare a datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a jquery datepicker that pick a date like this checkIn= 07/12/2015 which will pass as query string to next page.

In my database i have a startDate and endDate column that store datetime in this format 12/6/2015 12:00:00 AM

So how do i compare the selectDate with the startDate in database.
I try this

```
  Datetime checkIn = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["checkIn"], "MM-dd-yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but not work.

Comment: if your checkIn is in format ""dd/MM/yyyy", then you should use that as your ParseExact format

Comment: @JleruOHeP but my database is in "MM-dd-yyyy" format

Comment: On the server do you have your DB value as string as well? If so then you will have to parse it separately - with different format ("MM/dd/yyyy")

Comment: it's better and more easier to compare the date if you can store the date in  db in this format : yyyymmdd i.e 20150512. it's never repeat nor duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try hh instead of h in date format

Answer (score 0):

If you store dates in the databese as stings - you would need to parse them as well using different format ("MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" in your case):

```
var dbDateAsString = "12/30/2015 12:00:00 AM"; //30 Dec 2015
var checkIn = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["checkIn"], "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //07/12/2015 == 7 Dec 2015
var dbDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dbDateAsString, "MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
var result = checkIn > dbDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your database stores the dates as *date* values, not strings. The format, you describe, is for display only. If so:

```
string checkIn= "07/12/2015";
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(checkIn, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int compareStart = startDate.CompareTo(selectedDate);
int compareEnd = endDate.CompareTo(selectedDate);

bool accept = compareStart + compareEnd == 0;    
// or, to include start and end dates as acceptable:    
bool accept = Math.Abs(compareStart + compareEnd) <= 1;
```